# CSS Cursor property won't change the cursor while hovering over the element

Tags: html, css, cursor

I need to change the cursor when I hover over an element.

### Expected Result

The cursor should be a pointer when hovering over my `<div>`

### Actual Result

The cursor only changes while I am passing the mouse between the `div` and what is outside the `div`, but it doesn't stay while inside the `div`. The change is almost imperceptible, it's like as if it is applied to the `div` border instead of the whole div.

### Code

```
<div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; top: 381px; left: 277px; cursor:pointer;"></div>
```

Comment: I tried both your link to w3school and your div with Chrome (same ver. as yours) and IE 11 and both works

Comment: Thats really strange, I already tried restarting it. Will try to download again maybe if you say its working for you.

Comment: Could be that your positioning is messing it up. There should be no need for those positioning properties..I'd gues syou have layout issues.

Comment: So I ended up rebooting my computer after trying to close Chrome and open it again and now it is doing the expected behavior. Thanks to all for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There might have been issues with your browser at the time in 2014 when the question was originally posted.

For anyone else finding this question. Note that the code for `cursor: pointer` does work. Snippet below to show an example, original code modified to add size and color for demo purposes only.

```html
<div style="cursor:pointer; background-color: #f97709; width: 300px; height: 300px; top: 381px; left: 277px;"></div>
```